# GLEW & SFML on MacOS with #version 150 core

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glsl, sfml

I need to create some project with OpenGL on my MacOS Big Sur 11.2.2.

My versions:

```
Renderer:       AMD Radeon Pro 555 OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version: 2.1 ATI-4.2.15
GLSL version:   1.20
```

I need to render some shaders with version 150:

```
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;
out vec3 Color;
void main(){
Color = color;

gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);

}
)glsl";

const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec3 Color;
out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
}
)glsl";
```

And on rendering shaders I've got errors:

```
ERROR: 0:2: '' :  version '150' is not supported
ERROR: 0:2: '' : syntax error: #version
```

I must create my project on 1.5 version, so what should I do to run it on my MacBook? There is any option to render with 1.50 version or update my libraries?

**Full code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec3 position;
in vec3 color;
out vec3 Color;
void main(){
Color = color;

gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);

}
)glsl";

const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec3 Color;
out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
}
)glsl";
int main()
{
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.depthBits = 24;
    settings.stencilBits = 8;

    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800, 32), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close, settings);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

        const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
        const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
        const GLubyte* glslVersion = glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
        printf ("Renderer:       %s\n", renderer);
        printf ("OpenGL version: %s\n", version);
        printf ("GLSL version:   %s\n", glslVersion);
    
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);


    GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

    if(!status) {
        std::cout << "vertexShader: compile failed" << std::endl;
        char buffer[1024];
        
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    
    if(!status) {
        std::cout << "fragmentShader: compile failed" << std::endl;
        char buffer[1024];
        
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    //glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        sf::Event windowEvent;
        while (window.pollEvent(windowEvent)) {
            switch (windowEvent.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 3);
        window.display();
    }
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    window.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently trying to execute a OpenGL 3.3 core profile shader (version 150 core) in a OpenGL 2.1 context, which is not possible. If your hardware supports it, you can specifically request a 3.3 core profile context:

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.stencilBits = 8;
settings.majorVersion = 3;
settings.minorVersion = 3;
settings.attributeFlags = Core;
```

Comment: It's working with some errors/warnings, thanks. Can i reduce errors?

```Error. Unable to create the context. Retrying without shared context.
Warning. New context created without shared context.
Warning: The created OpenGL context does not fully meet the settings that were requested
Requested: version = 4.4 ; depth bits = 24 ; stencil bits = 8 ; AA level = 0 ; core = true ; debug = false ; sRGB = false
Created: version = 4.1 ; depth bits = 24 ; stencil bits = 8 ; AA level = 0 ; core = true ; debug = false ; sRGB = false```

Comment: MacOS does not support OpenGL 4.4. Did you use exactly the code in my answer or did you change major and minor to 4?

Comment: With major and minor 3 still have some warnings: ```Error. Unable to create the context. Retrying without shared context.
Warning. New context created without shared context.```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get rid of the last warning. OpenGL support on MacOS is a bit problematic with SFML.